# Total Value in a mysql Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a sum of values from my database that have different datetime stamps. I aim to return a total for each day of all the values in the table for that date. My store Procedure looks like the following:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE get_reads;
CREATE PROCEDURE get_reads (IN  device varchar (20), IN start_date datetime, IN end_date datetime, IN read_type varchar(8))

BEGIN

    SELECT dr.date_time, sum(dr.device_reading)
    FROM DEVICE_DETAILS dd,
    DEVICE_READING dr
    WHERE dr.device_id = dd.device_id
    AND dd.serial_number = device
    AND dr.date_time BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    AND dr.reading_type = read_type;



END//
```

I Believe I will have to use a tempory table or something but cannot find any advice online regarding my situation.For each day I have a value every half hour and I want the stored porocedure to return these totalled for each day within the date range I pass in. The database columns look like so

```
+-----------+---------------------+--------------+----------------+-------+
| device_id | date_time           | reading_type | device_reading | units |
+-----------+---------------------+--------------+----------------+-------+
| E1        | 2012-11-19 00:29:00 | Profile      |   0.0719131800 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 00:59:00 | Profile      |   0.0802306700 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 01:29:00 | Profile      |   0.0767434100 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 01:59:00 | Profile      |   0.0737920500 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 02:29:00 | Profile      |   0.0794256700 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 02:59:00 | Profile      |   0.0729868200 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 03:29:00 | Profile      |   0.0745970500 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 03:59:00 | Profile      |   0.0804993100 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 04:29:00 | Profile      |   0.0837193100 | KW    |
| E1        | 2012-11-19 04:59:00 | Profile      |   0.0483004600 | KW    |
```

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: That each value is returned individually by time frame and I want a total for the whole day.

Comment: But... procedures do not return anything. They just "do things" :-?

Comment: no surprise. you forgot a `group by` clause.

Comment: How to u group by date when there is also a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

resolved using CAST(datetime AS DATE);

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE get_reads;
CREATE PROCEDURE get_reads (IN  device varchar (20), IN start_date datetime, IN end_date datetime, IN read_type varchar(8))

    BEGIN

            SELECT dr.date_time, sum(dr.device_reading)
            FROM DEVICE_DETAILS dd,
            DEVICE_READING dr
            WHERE dr.device_id = dd.device_id
            AND dd.serial_number = device
            AND dr.date_time BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
            AND dr.reading_type = read_type
            GROUP BY CAST(dr.date_time AS DATE);



    END//
```